# asyncio.wait_for exec function error in Python3.7.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I try to run this code:

```py
import asyncio

async def eva(code):
    exec("async def ex(): return {}".format(code))
    return await asyncio.wait_for(locals()["ex"](), timeout=1.0)

async def main():
    while True:
        code = input()
        x = await asyncio.wait_for(eva(code), timeout=1.0)
        print(x)
asyncio.run(main())
```

And getting following error:

> ````
> <module>
>
>     asyncio.run(main())   File "C:\Users\\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\runners.py",
> line 43, in run
>
>     return loop.run_until_complete(main)   File "C:\Users\\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 584, in run_until_complete
>     return future.result()
>
>   File "eval.py", line 10, in main
>
>     x = await asyncio.wait_for(eva(code), timeout=1.0)   File "C:\Users\\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\tasks.py",
> line 416, in wait_for
>     return fut.result()
>
>   File "eval.py", line 5, in eva
>
>     return await asyncio.wait_for(locals()["ex"](), timeout=1.0)
>
>   File "C:\Users\\
> {user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\tasks.py",
> line 416, in wait_for
>
>     return fut.result()
>
>   File "<string>", line 1, in ex TypeError: 'int' object is not
> iterable ```
> ````

Can you help me to understand what exactly happens?

Comment: What's your input? Broken input is the only way to cause that.

Answer (score 0):

From traceback you can see that error happend at function `ex`:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in ex
```

And shortly before it this line was executed:

```
File "eval.py", line 5, in eva
    return await asyncio.wait_for(locals()["ex"](), timeout=1.0)
```

In other words exception was raised somewhere inside coroutine `ex` you  got from `locals()["ex"]`.

---

Exception message is:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

You can google it to understand typical situation when it can happen, but it's not hard to assume either: something inside `ex` tried to iterate object of type `int`.

Something like this happened:

```
import asyncio


async def ex():
    for i in 123:
        pass

async def main():
    return await asyncio.wait_for(ex(), timeout=1.0)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Run and you'll see similar:

```
  File "...\main.py", line 15, in main
    return await asyncio.wait_for(ex(), timeout=1.0)
  File "...\python37\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 416, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "...\main.py", line 11, in ex
    for i in 123:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```